# Yii suppors for handeling cookies and sessions for mobile devices

Tags: php, iphone, yii

we are developing an i-phone application, which has server side coding in YII PHP framework, my question is,is there any way to handle login sessions and cookies for mobile device or is there any settings which YII supports for handling cookies and sessions for device. please help in same..

i guess Yii provide some solution for this, let me know if anybody know about it.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone's mobile browser isn't all that different from a normal desktop browser, so there's no need for a specific handler for sessions on a mobile device. You can just use [Yii's CHttpSession class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession):

```
$session=new CHttpSession;
$session->open();
$value1=$session['name1'];  // get session variable 'name1'
$value2=$session['name2'];  // get session variable 'name2'
foreach($session as $name=>$value) // traverse all session variables
$session['name3']=$value3;  // set session variable 'name3'
```

Comment: Hi Louis Bataillard, Could u please explore it, i phone application dose not use browser, it is app, and i want to know how exactly we can handle the cookies and session on device.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I totally misinterpreted your question. As I'm a web-developer so I don't know anything about the iOS SDK so I can't help you with any client-side issues. Sorry. Perhaps you should edit your question and tags because it looks like you're working on a web-application. :)